# Selecting an ASP.NET RIA framework for rapid development?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, ria, componentone

We have an ASP.NET silverlight application, which is becoming limited by the requirement to have Silverlight installed.

I'd like to switch to a new framework, but don't want to have to build an entire new system from scratch.  Ideally I'd like to find a third-party framework that has all of the basics available right out of the box, so we can start adding our pages to the application and use our current business logic (mostly WCF calls).  Telerik & ComponentOne seem like good places to start, but so far I haven't seen either of them have a "complete" application that we can use as a starting point.  Am I missing something?  Can you suggest other frameworks?  I'm really looking for something that gives us a great jumping off point to develop a rich UI in as little time as possible.

Some features I'd like to see are:

- User authentication/registration/preferences
- Custmomizable Site navigation map
- Pages avaialble based upon roles
- Rich UI experience (right clicks a plus)

Answer (score 1):

I can speak for Telerik as I am one of the evangelist for Telerik. We at telerik have 70+ controls on the ASP.NET AJAX front and they all are RAD controls. You can just drag and drop and you have the flexibility to use a GUI to set the properties or through HTML or through code behind. We complement whatever ASP.NET has to offer and because of that there is no separate learning curve involved.

To get you a feel of completeness - I suggest that you take a look at the following integration examples - an end to end scenario apps.

Olympic Games - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/sample-applications/olympic-games/

Image Gallery - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/imagegallery/

Sales Dashboard - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/salesdashboard/

Rent A Car - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/carrental/

Schedule Builder - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/schedulebuilder/

Web Mail - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/webmail/

Ecommerce - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ecommercestore/

Whats more - all these demos can be downloaded and you will get the source code. So you can base your project right out of these samples.

Please go through all the above integration examples. Hope this provides some insight into your decision making process.

Also we do have an HTML5 based JavaScript UI framework called Kendo UI. This is a complete client side control rendering using javascript which will speed up your apps like anything. And this can be used in ASP.NET MVC scenarios as this fits very well in those. Nevertheless whether you use MVC or not you can still make use of the HTML5 based JavaScript Widgets available as part of the Kendo UI on any web application platform.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html

Hope this helps you !